# How to determine that a jvm app does more GC than normal work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, garbage-collection, jvm, amazon-elb, autoscaling

We recently had a problem that our EC2 instances had 90-100 percent cpu load cause of a bug in a library we include that created to many objects instead of reusing them (which was easy solvable), so we spent too much time in GC.

Unfortunately the AWS health checks and instance status metrics didn't cause the overloaded instances to be stopped and then new ones restarted, so after some time we hit the max autoscaling number and....died. Also our own health checks inside the app which are used for the ELB are so simple that they answered often enough to obviously not cause the instances to be terminated...and restarted, which would mitigate that problem for quite some time.

My idea is now to use our custom health check which is already included in the ELB health checks to report a failure if we spent to much time in GC.

How would I do such a thing inside the app?

Comment: All nice suggestions, but I don't want to connect via a tool but report it from inside the app e.g. via Http call. So i want to calc it also from inside...

Comment: `GCTimeRatio` should actually prevent this and throw a overhead limit exceeded OOME when too much time is spent on GC.

Comment: This was not the case for our app. It was still responding but not good enough. We have about 5000 to 20000 req per minute for 3 instances

Comment: The default, depending on configuration, is something around 1% to 15% GC overhead. Unless you have overridden some relevant JVM arguments I would expect an OOME to happen.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of JVM parameters that allow GC monitoring

```
-Xloggc:<file> // logs gc activity to a file
-XX:+PrintGCDetails // tells you how different generations are impacted
```

You can either parse these logs yourself or use specific tool such as GCViewer to analyse gc activity.

Comment: And from inside the app?

Comment: I see... Haven't tried this but  GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo seems to do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Use [GarbageCollectorMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html):

```
    long gcTime = 0;
    for (GarbageCollectorMXBean gcBean : ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()) {
        gcTime += gcBean.getCollectionTime();
    }

    long jvmUptime = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime();

    System.out.println("GC ratio: " + (100 * gcTime / jvmUptime) + "%");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/) to monitor what happens inside the JVM and you can monitor remote instances via JMX. You did not describe which application container that you are using (Apache Tomcat, GlassFish etc.), you can set up a JMX connector [like this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/monitoring.html) in the case of Tomcat.

Don't forget to adjust Security Groups in AWS to have the proper permission to access the JMX port.

Comment: We don't use any container. We use the play framework. Therefore we want to use/calc  it from inside the app

Comment: I know these tools but I want to calc it from inside the app and let the ELB decide to kill the instance by inspecting the status code. E.g. we would deliver a non 200 code if we spent more than 75 percent in the GC.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM flags `PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime` and `PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime` will log how long the application was active or suspended. They're a bit of a misnomers since they actually measure time spent in and out of safepoints, not just GCs.

Comment: I would like to calc it from inside the app